# Std output is correct but Output column is empty in leet code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I solved a simple leet code problem the std output is correct but output is not. At first I thought it was because I am printing not returning the value, but the same problem occurs even if I return it.

Can someone help me with this

Thank you in advance

```py
class jimpack:

    def reduce(num):
        if(num%2==0):
            num=num/2
        elif(num%2==1):
         num=num-1
        return num

    def main(self):
        m = int(input("enter input"))
        count=0
        num=0
        while m>0:
            m = jimpack.reduce(m)
            count=count+1
        print(count)
        return count   
 
c = jimpack()
c.main()
```

[picture of code and leet code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUzWq.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with another question in python...

found this in looking for answers and helped me alot so hopefully it helps you too.

https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011834174-I-encountered-Wrong-Answer-Runtime-Error-for-a-specific-test-case-When-I-test-my-code-using-this-test-case-it-produced-the-correct-output-Why-

https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).